# Array index going out of range, stopping the for loop it is inside of

Tags: c#, debugging, for-loop, unity-game-engine

My index is still going out of range in my **list**, inventory, even after I added an if statement that stops inventory [i] from being called once i is greater than the inventory's count (so the inventory items that doesn't exist won't be called), once the inventory[i]'s ID is equal to -1 (The default ID value for empty items), and when number is greater than 1 (To draw the texture only once). I have been stuck on this bug for hours, but nothing I'm trying is working. There were supposed to be a total of 25 boxes, but only 11 were drawn. I noticed that when I change the value of y to two, the error stops The relevant part of my code is below. I deleted the rest for ease of reading. Thank you in advance

```
void DrawInventory()
{
    int y = 5;
    int x = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) 
    {
        int number = 0;
        number++;
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) 
        {
            Rect rect = new Rect (new Vector2 (100 + (i * 60), 0 + (j * 60)), new Vector2 (50, 50));
            GUI.Box (rect, "");
            if (inventory [i].ID != -1 && number == 1 && i < inventory.Count) 
            {
                GUI.DrawTexture (rect, inventory [i].Icon);
                number++;
                print (inventory.Count);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Picture of Error]

Comment: inventory is List or array?

Comment: @Programmer It is a list. I mentioned it in the first line of my question.

Comment: I missed that part. things are easier to read when bold is used sometimes.

Comment: Good. You bold the important parts.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1):

In the line `if (inventory [i].ID != -1 && number == 1 && i < inventory.Count)`, `inventory[i]` is evaluated before `i < inventory.Count`.

You can fix it by making `i < inventory.Count` the first check.

### Update

After the initial answer, the question asker asked:

> Why is it that I must make `i < inventory.Count` my first check?

This is because the `&&` operator *short-circuits*. What that means is that whenever the left hand side is `false`, will not be executed anymore, because `false && whatever` will never be `true`.

`if (i < inventory.Count && inventory[i].ID)` will therefore never execute the right hand side if `i` is indeed smaller than `inventory.Count`.

If, however, the condition is `if (inventory[i].ID && i < inventory.Count)`, the left hand side is executed first and that is where the application crashes if `i` is too large. The right hand side will never be executed.

Comment: was typing that and saw the solution. +1. that should be the problem

Comment: I had no idea that the order in which the conditions were checked mattered, but it apparently does. Shouldn't the code still check all of the conditions before executing though? Why is it that I must make " i < inventory.Count" my first check? Thank you! @BartvanNierop

Comment: When evaluating multiple conditionals in a single statement, `&&` and `||` short-circuit. When evaluating `false && true`, the right hand side is ignored, because whatever is there can never make the entire statement `true` anymore. The same is true for `true || false`, which can never be `false` after the left hand side is evaluated.

Comment: @AaronGe Since comments are not meant to last, I updated the answer to answer your question in the comment.